# String Operations Confusion? ELI5

Tags: python-3.x

I'm extremely new to python and I have no idea why this code gives me this output. I tried searching around for an answer but couldn't find anything because I'm not sure what to search for.

An explain-like-I'm-5 explanation would be greatly appreciated

```
astring = "hello world"
print(astring[3:7:2])
```

This gives me : "l"

Also

```
astring = "hello world"
print(astring[3:7:3])
```

gives me :  "lw"

I can't wrap my head around why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is string slicing in python.
Slicing is similar to regular string indexing, but it can return a just a section of a string.

Using two parameters in a slice, such as `[a:b]` will return a string of characters, starting at index `a` up to, but not including, index `b`.
For example:

`"abcdefg"[2:6]` would return `"cdef"`

Using three parameters performs a similar function, but the slice will only return the character after a chosen gap. For example `[2:6:2]` will return every second character beginning at index 2, up to index 5.
ie `"abcdefg"[2:6:2]` will return `ce`, as it only counts every second character.

In your case, `astring[3:7:3]`, the slice begins at index 3 (the second `l`) and moves forward the specified 3 characters (the third parameter) to `w`. It then stops at index 7, returning `lw`.

In fact when using only two parameters, the third defaults to 1, so `astring[2:5]` is the same as `astring[2:5:1]`.

[Python Central](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) has some more detailed explanations of cutting and slicing strings in python.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you are over complicating this slightly.
Since the string astring is set statically you could more easily do the following:

```
# Sets the characters for the letters in the consistency of the word
letter-one = "h"
letter-two = "e"
letter-three = "l"
letter-four = "l"
letter-six = "o"
letter-7 = " "
letter-8 = "w"
letter-9 = "o"
letter-10 = "r"
letter11 = "l"
lettertwelve = "d"

# Tells the python which of the character letters that you want to have on the print screen
print(letter-three + letter-7 + letter-three)
```

This way its much more easily readable to human users and it should mitigate your error.